# TestFlight: Testers are not getting notified of new builds

Tags: testflight

Since Apple moved to their new and improved TestFlight website, none of my internal or external users are receiving push notifications or emails when I make a new build available for testing.

These are testers who previously were getting push and emails with each new build.

If the tester goes to the TestFlight app on their device, they do see the new build is available for update there.

I see a couple threads about this in the Apple Developer forums but nobody seems to know how to work around this problem:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76020

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76131

Anyone here found a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I saw this issue as well.  Did you ever find a way around this?

Comment: I've stopped using the "Automatically Notify" option and always manually click Notify Testers. That seems to work every time.

But that means internal testers don't get notified 'til the external testers get notified. :-(

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Where can I find this option?  I did not see it anywhere in their UI

Comment: The Automatically Notify checkbox appears in the bottom left of the dialog box when you submit the build to beta approval on the iTunes Connect website. Make sure you clear that checkbox. And then, after the beta approval is complete, go back in to that build in iTunes Connect website and you should see an action button in the top right corner "Notify Testers."

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The new TestFlight allows simultaneous testing of multiple builds. Did you expire the older build? If so, how did you do it? Or did you leave the build active?
Only 13 of our 500 active testers have installed the new update over the last 30 days, only because they stumbled over the Update-button in the TestFlight app..
Any **real** solutions to this, other than turning off Automatically?

Comment: I never expire older builds (maybe that's the problem?) I still have not found a proper solution for this other than turning off Automatic.

Answer (score 1):

when submitting a build for beta approval, uncheck 'automatically notify' in lower left corner. then after beta is approved for external testing, click 'notify testers' in upper right corner. if i recall next time i do this, i'll include screenshots.

this solution is from @boozedog, it fixed the issue for me, and i am submitting @boozedog's comments as an answer. the text of his comment:
"
The Automatically Notify checkbox appears in the bottom left of the dialog box when you submit the build to beta approval on the iTunes Connect website. Make sure you clear that checkbox. And then, after the beta approval is complete, go back in to that build in iTunes Connect website and you should see an action button in the top right corner "Notify Testers."
"